# Derivative of Heaviside Function and Equivalence

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta

The derivative of the Heaviside function $\theta(x - a)$ is normally taken to be the delta function $\delta(x - a)$.

This question has two parts, the first is whether a constant coefficient is introduced when differentiating the Heaviside function. According to Wolframalpha (I know it is not the best reference site but unable to find information elsewhere),
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\theta(x/a - 1) = \frac{1}{a}\delta(x/a - 1),$$
whereas,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\theta(x-a) = \delta(x - a),$$
although these two Heaviside functions are essentially the same. Wolframalpha: [first equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+heaviside%28x%2Fa+-+1%29) [second equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+heaviside%28x-a%29).

The second part is whether is is correct to say that,
$$\theta(x - a) = \theta(x/a - 1),$$
which the above seems to imply is not true but I would normally freely switch between the two. I guess a similar question would be if,
$$\delta(x - a) = \delta(x/a - 1).$$

This could be a mistake by me in either formulating the problem or not really a proper mathematical question (I am a physicist and so skirt the boundaries of mathematical rigour).

Many thanks

Comment: Do you believe that $f(x)=f(x/a)$ for a function $f$?

Comment: @Dr.MV You need to be careful, the $-a$ was replaced with $-1$ as well. In fact as functions $\theta(x/a-1)=\theta(x-a)$, since $\theta$ only cares about the sign.

Comment: @Ian Yes I know that.  Substitute, if you will, $y=x-a$.  Then, ask "Is $f(y)=f(y/a)$?"  Do you understand where I was going now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to know $\frac{d}{dx} \theta(x/a-1)$. You write the definition:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d}{dx} \left ( \theta(x/a-1) \right ) f(x) dx = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \theta(x/a-1) f'(x) dx = -\int_a^\infty f'(x) dx = f(a)$$

Thus $\frac{d}{dx} \theta(x/a-1) = \delta(x-a)$ in the sense of distribution theory. But this is the same as $\frac{1}{a} \delta(x/a-1)$, because of the definition of $\delta(x/a-1)$.

Comment: How is the chain rule not valid when we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\theta(x/a-1)=\delta (x-a)=\frac1a \delta(x/a-1)=\frac{d}{d(x/a)}\theta(x/a-1)\frac{d(x/a)}{dx}?$$

Comment: @Dr.MV Oh, I see your point, you have to change variables in the delta as well. Let me edit.

Comment: No worry. I don't down vote.

Comment: In fact, +1 for the nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. Makes sense, I should have looked up the definition of $\delta(x/a-1)$ before asking, guess I will need to be more careful when switching between the two in the future.